# I can't find the subject of a verb in this sentence…

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I read a text of Winnicott (Psychologist) and have a problem with this sentence:

> By this definition an infant's babbling and the way in which an older
> child goes over a repertory of songs and tunes while preparing for
> sleep come within the intermediate area as transitional phenomena,
> along with the use made of objects that are not part of the infant's
> body yet **are** not fully recognized as belonging to external reality.

What is the grammatical subject of the "are" which I marked as bold?

Comment: The subject appears to be the noun phrase "objects (that are not part of the infant's body)". Note that the bracketed relative clause modifies "objects" and hence is part of the NP subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relative clause marked by "that"

> ... objects that are not part...

This relative clause has two coordinated subclasses

> are not part...  yet are not fully...

The subjects of these clauses are not explicit, but implicitly the subject is the noun that is being described by these relative clauses, that is "objects".

So the subject of the verb "are" is "objects", in a relative structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solved my problem completely!